# How to set preferred version in Scene Builder?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

There is an issue I'm facing with Scene Builder where it keeps overwriting the JavaFX version to 15.0.1 whereas I am using version 11.0.2, so I get this warning when running:

```
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 15.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 11.0.2
```

I just edit the version number in the .fxml file:

```
<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="293.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
```

But when I make any changes in Scene Builder, it puts it back to 15.0.1 and I get the warning.

How can I fix this?

Comment: @Abra true, but the problem seems to be that scenebuilder insists on adding the overspecified default namespace tag (on every edit) - there must be some configuration option to make _not_ add the exact version

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since SceneBuilder takes:
`System.getProperty("javafx.version")` as check for its namespace. Maybe try to set this to desired version.

Edit:
Open configuration file where your ScenBuilder is installed: e.g.:

```
C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\app\SceneBuilder.cfg
```

Inside under [JavaOptions] add:

```
java-options=-Djavafx.version=null
```

You can set it to your current version, but if it is set to NULL it wont check versions or put warning even you open FXML file in SceneBuilder with other version of JavaFX.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I am using the null version you posted right now, I was wondering if the warning has any weight to it? Will I run into issues due to the different versions in the future or is it better to set the version I am using?

Comment: About issues: I'm not sure about that. So far I didn't have any problems. What I can tell from code namespace is not used anywhere else. But I hope someone else with more information can answer that.