# JavaFX 11 version not matches with SceneBuilder xmlns 16

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

When I use Scene Builder the xmlns value set to unexpected 16 version. I have java 11 and JavaFX 11, while Scene Builder set's it to 16. I would like to see 11 version in fxml files.

I see Scene Builder version 16 only available to download here https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download and I see it can be used with JavaFX 11:

> Scene Builder 16.0.0 was released on Mar 26, 2021. You can use this Scene Builder version together with Java 11 and higher.

How to make xmlns value assigned by Scene Builder match to JavaFX version used? If would I not fix this version problem would it cause any errors?

Here the xmlns assigned by Scene Builder in fxml:

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="1850.0"
            prefWidth="1080.0" styleClass="golfistbg" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
```

I have java 11 installed

```
~$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And my maven pom file contains java fx reference:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <javafx.version>11.0.2</javafx.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency> ...
```

Comment: don't specify the version in the fxml .. ah, just seeing that scenebuilder adds it: there might be a configuration option in scenebuilder that I don't know, sry ;)

Comment: If I will remove version in fxml file, will Scene Builder use 11 version?

Comment: don't know, I don't use scenebuilder ;)

Comment: The xmlns value is dependent on the version of Scene Builder itself. The specified values in the pom are irrelevant for this.  Scene Builder 16 will set it to 16,  Scene Builder 11 to 11 (or 11.0.1) etc. The mismatch should not be a problem. I would not worry.

Comment: @anko can't be scenebuilder be configured somehow to _not_ set it? It's not really needed anyway, except when wanting to use version-specific classes, properties .. we hadn't had much change in recent versions

Comment: There is a related question with an accepted answer: ["How to set preferred version in Scene Builder?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65987397/how-to-set-preferred-version-in-scene-builder).  I didn't try the suggested fix to see if it works.

Comment: @jewelsea I saw this answer, though I not understood it. It says about two different solutions. Also I not see any of them documented (tried google). Last thing I not get is scene builder 16 compatible to JavaFX 11. I thought versions changed for reason ...

Comment: I advise you [contact Gluon](https://gluonhq.com/about-us/contact-us/), who runs support for SceneBuilder.