# Can the target version of FXML generated by Gluon Scenebuilder be changed?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml, gluon

I am using Gluon Scene Builder to graphically create the FXML files for a **Java 8** based program.

Gluon Scene Builder will generate the FXML file successfully, however it will place the attribute `xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1"` in the `root` node of the FXML document. Notice that the version is incorrect for my needs.

**Is there a way to change the target version in Gluon Scene Builder itself? Is it possible to disable adding a version at all?** For example, `xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/"` from Gluon Scene Builder itself? I would like this to be applied to all scenes I create using this program.

I am using scene builder from Eclipse, to which I have linked it. Eclipse is configured to use JDK 8. Gluon Scene Builder ignores these settings. I have looked into the `File > Preferences...` of Scene Builder and there is no option to change the target Java version.

I am fixing the generated FXML documents manually, but this is troublesome, as I often forget to fix the version and I get a warning each time I open the scenes when I run the program I am working on.

"Scene Builder for Java 8" is quite old (Jun 5, 2018, version 8.5.0 compared to 16.0.0 currently). Scene Builder is generally slow and buggy, I would like to avoid using an old version, although I am aware it is a possible solution.

I can not upgrade the project's Java version to anything other than Java 8 due to requirements imposed by dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 

However, I used the solution found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65987397/how-to-set-preferred-version-in-scene-builder with the modification of `java-options=-Djavafx.version=` instead of `java-options=-Djavafx.version=null` as the result was `xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/null"` with the one in the accepted answer. The result is  `xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/"`